# Can a panel analysis be run with only 2 firms?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, small-sample

I would like to perform a regression. I have 10 years of financial performance (ROA) on only 2 companies. There are two independent variables: the companies'  credit risk and market risk. Based on research I have done these are panel data, but my concern is whether this is enough data? Also what would be the best way to estimate a model using these data (OLS，PLS, or a fixed effect panel data model)?

Below is the complete dataset:

```
Year    Financial Performance   Credit RISK     Market risk     Firm
2006    2.40%                  $3.9  billion $12.3 million   Company A
2007    3.70%                  $1.6  billion $16.1 million   Company A
2008    7.90%                  $5.6  billion $20.5 million   Company A
2009    4.20%                  $2.6  billion $20.5 million   Company A
2010    9.60%                  $3.0  billion $20.3 million   Company A
2011    13.20%                 $2.8  billion $20.6 million   Company A
2012    5.90%                  $3.9  billion $9.8  million   Company A
2013    2.10%                  $2.1  billion $16.3 million   Company A
2014    1.30%                  $1.6  billion $12.2 million   Company A
2015    2.40%                  $1.4  billion $11.7 million   Company A
2016    4.50%                  $1.1  billion $16.3 million   Company A
Year    Financial Performance   Credit RISK     Market risk         Firm
2006    9.20%                   $187million  $92 million    Company B
2007    8.50%                   $400million  $96 million    Company B
2008    7.50%                   $197million  $337 million   Company B
2009    7.20%                   $99million    $291 million   Company B
2010    6.70%                   $85million      $223 million   Company B
2011    5.20%                   $86million    $218 million   Company B
2012    4.80%                   $4million      $128 million   Company B
2013    5.35%                   $37million    $114 million   Company B
2014    3.20%                   $162million  $54 million    Company B
2015    2.40%                   $219million  $145 million   Company B
2016    2.50%                   $352million  $111 million   Company B
```

Comment: I would like to perform a regression. I have for 2 companies and for a duration of 10 years their financial performane (ROA) this would be the dependent variable. The independent variables are two major risk affecting the company credit risk and market risk. Based on research l have done this data is panal data but my concern is that is this good enough panal data? Also between OLS ，PLS and fixed effect panal data models which would be the best way to estimate using this data?

Comment: By question good panal data，l want to know if the number of observations or sample points enough.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.